# findDecoder imread_('cat.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.7

I have not solved the following problem (Python 3.9.13, Win10).

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('cat.jpg,', 3)
print(img)
cv.imshow('cat', img)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

`print(img)` was `None`

The size of cat.jpg is 372Kb.

There is cat.jpg which located at the same level of python `code1.py`.
Also, I installed opencv-python-headless.

Then, I ran it. Following waning appeared;

```
    [ WARN:0@0.758].......oadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('cat.jpg'):
    can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
```

Comment: Check your flag `3` what does it stands for? `3` does not stand for any flag. All flag valuescan be found here https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html

Comment: look closely at the syntax highlighting of the filename argument of `imread`

Comment: naming your script `code.,py` is not very descriptive, you end up with names `code1.py`, `code2.py`

Comment: As the content of the filename parameter is relative (contains only a filename) your problem could be related to the location where your working directory points to. As normally relative paths are appended to the working directory.  
The following code prints the absolut path of ```cat.jpg``` depending on the location where you start the code.
`python -c "import os; print(os.path.abspath('cat.jpg'))"`